# In Pride and Prejudice, how did Lady Catherine find out about Darcy's proposal?

Tags: jane-austen, pride-and-prejudice

In *Pride and Prejudice*, there is a part where Lady Catherine visited the Bennets. She wished to ward off Elizabeth and wanted her to refuse Darcy's proposal and was stumped.

How did Lady Catherine find out about Darcy's proposal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The scene you refer to takes place in chapter 56. In Chapter 57 we read:

> from what the report of their engagement could originate, Elizabeth was at a loss to imagine; till she recollected that *his* being the intimate friend of Bingley, and *her* being the sister of Jane, was enough, at a time when the expectation of one wedding made everybody eager for another, to supply the idea. She had not herself forgotten to feel that the marriage of her sister must bring them more frequently together. And her neighbours at Lucas Lodge, therefore (for through their communication with the Collinses, the report, she concluded, had reached Lady Catherine), had only set *that* down as almost certain and immediate, which *she* had looked forward to as possible at some future time.

So Elizabeth is pondering how Lady Catherine found out, she remembers that the respective closeness of Darcy and herself to Bingley and Jane, whom everyone is expecting will marry, is enough to give rise to a general expectation that one wedding will lead to another.

She had, herself, thought that she would see Darcy more often once Jane and Bingley wed, and that Charlotte's family at Lucas Lodge had likely taken that fact as indicative of a certainty of a match and communicated that to Mr Collins and Charlotte.

This is borne out a little later on when Mr Bennet calls Elizabeth to his study to discuss a letter he has received from Mr Collins: (bolding mine)

> 'I have received a letter this morning that has astonished me exceedingly. As it principally concerns yourself, you ought to know its contents. I did not know before, that I had **two daughters on the brink of matrimony**. Let me congratulate you on a very important conquest.”
>
> The colour now rushed into Elizabeth’s cheeks in the instantaneous conviction of its being a letter from the nephew, instead of the aunt; and she was undetermined whether most to be pleased that he explained himself at all, or offended that his letter was not rather addressed to herself; when her father continued:
>
> “You look conscious. Young ladies have great penetration in such matters as these; but I think I may defy even your sagacity, to discover the name of your admirer. **This letter is from Mr. Collins**.”
>
> “From Mr. Collins! and what can he have to say?”
>
> “Something very much to the purpose of course. He begins with congratulations on the approaching nuptials of my eldest daughter, of which, it seems, **he has been told by some of the good-natured, gossiping Lucases**. I shall not sport with your impatience, by reading what he says on that point. What relates to yourself, is as follows: ‘Having thus offered you the sincere congratulations of Mrs. Collins and myself on this happy event, let me now add a short hint on the subject of another; of which we have been advertised by the same authority. **Your daughter Elizabeth, it is presumed, will not long bear the name of Bennet**, after her elder sister has resigned it, and the chosen partner of her fate may be reasonably looked up to as one of the most illustrious personages in this land.’
>
> “Can you possibly guess, Lizzy, who is meant by this? ‘This young gentleman is blessed, in a peculiar way, with every thing the heart of mortal can most desire,—splendid property, noble kindred, and extensive patronage. Yet in spite of all these temptations, let me warn my cousin Elizabeth, and yourself, of what evils you may incur by a precipitate closure with this gentleman’s proposals, which, of course, you will be inclined to take immediate advantage of.’
>
> “Have you any idea, Lizzy, who this gentleman is? But now it comes out:
>
> “‘My motive for cautioning you is as follows. We have reason to imagine that his aunt, Lady Catherine de Bourgh, does not look on the match with a friendly eye.’
>
> “**Mr. Darcy, you see, is the man! Now, Lizzy, I think I have surprised you. Could he, or the Lucases, have pitched on any man within the circle of our acquaintance, whose name would have given the lie more effectually to what they related**? Mr. Darcy, who never looks at any woman but to see a blemish, and who probably never looked at you in his life! It is admirable!”